# Maven errors during protobuf jar compiling

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

During compilation of protobuf jar, when executing `mvn test` I got the following error:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0: Could not transfer artifact com.google:google:pom:1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.IllegalStateException and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0 (/home/capo/bin/protobuf-2.5.0/java/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0: Could not transfer artifact com.google:google:pom:1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.IllegalStateException and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was…

Change OpenJDK to Oracle Java.

Comment: And why would that solve the problem?  Because such problems are usually resolved in a completely different way...

Comment: @john16384 I really don't know and I lost too much time for this to be curious. I think it is caused by protobuf-openjdk compability issues. I decided to leave this answer, because googling this error did not suggest changing JVM.